# Error : is not a function. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, function

This is my lift programm. But I have error.

```
var person = {
  name: "Roman",
  position: 2,
  goal: 9
};

var lift = {
  getPosition : function() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  return x; 
} ()};

console.log("Ok " + person.name + "! You are at " + person.position + " floor");
console.log("Lift is at " + lift.getPosition() + " floor");
```

> Error lift.getPosition is not a function.

How can I fix it??

Comment: `function(){}` is an anonymous function declaration. But `function(){}()` is an anonymous function call, which is not what you want here, because now `lift.getPosition` would just be an integer, not a function.

Answer (score 4):

you code looks broken:

```
var lift = {
  getPosition : function() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  return x; 
} ()};
```

it seems this should be

```
var lift = {
  getPosition : function() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    return x; 
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declared getPosition you assigned this property a self invoked anonymous function. (The `()` at the end, self invokes it)

```
var lift = {
  getPosition: function() {
      var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        return x; 
  }()
};
```

You can remove them `()` and call the method like you did "`lift.getPosition()`":

```
var lift = {
    getPosition: function() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        return x; 
    }
};

console.log("Lift is at " + lift.getPosition() + " floor");
```

or leave them and just call the property without the `()` "`lift.getPosition`":

```
var lift = {
    getPosition: function() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        return x; 
    }()
};

console.log("Lift is at " + lift.getPosition + " floor");
```

But that would return the same value every time you use it, because it is only executed once. It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.